# Function Never Ends Inside Switch Statement?

Tags: c++, function, class, switch-statement

I am having a bit of an issue getting my functions to break in my switch statement. The way I want the program to work is :
-user selects an option from menu
-function completes
-returns to main menu.

However, the "setuserdetails" function keeps executing repeatedly even after the details have already been entered: any advice? thanks in advance.

**users.h**

```
#ifndef USERS_H
#define USERS_H


#include <string>


using namespace std;
class Users

{
public:
    //Users();
    void SetUserDetails(string &sName, string &sSurname, string &sEmail, int &iAge, char &Gender);
    void ReturnUserDetails(string &sName, string &sSurname, string &sEmail, int &iAge, char &Gender);
private:
    string sName;
    string sSurname;
    string sEmail;
    int iAge;
    char cGender;


};
#endif
```

**users.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "users.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

/*Users::Users()
{

}*/
void Users::SetUserDetails(string &sName, string &sSurname, string &sEmail, int &iAge, char &Gender)
{

        cout << "Welcome to the Customer Details Section" << endl; //enter user details
        cout << "Please Enter Your Name: " << endl;
        cin >> sName;
        cout << "Please Enter Your Surname: " << endl;
        cin >> sSurname;
        cout << "Welcome " << sName << " Please Now enter Your Email Address: " << endl;
        cin >> sEmail;
        cout << "Now Please Enter Your age  " << sName << " : " << endl;
        cin >> iAge;
        cout << "Finally, Please enter your Gender (as M for male or F for Female): " << endl;
        cin >> cGender;
        return;
}


void Users::ReturnUserDetails(string &sName, string &sSurname, string &sEmail, int &iAge, char &Gender)
{
    cout << "Thank you for logging on to the system: your Details are as follows:" << endl; //show user details, printed out to console 

    cout << "Name: " << sName << " " << sSurname << endl;
    cout << "Email Address: " << sEmail << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << iAge << " Gender: " << cGender << endl;

    cout << "Please start ordering your Items!" << endl;

    return;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include "menu.h"
#include "users.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //declare variables
    //variables for main menu navigation
    Menu menu; //object of the menu class 
    Users user; //object of the user class 
    menu.ShowMainMenu();
    int iChoice; //user input 
    cin >> iChoice; //get user input

    //user details 
    string sFirstName; //intialise string 
    string sSurname;
    string sEmailAddress;
    int iAge = 0; //intialise char
    char cGender ='a'; //intialise char


    do
    { 


        switch (iChoice)
        {
            //if user presses 1
        case 1:
            for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 1; iCount++)
            {
                user.SetUserDetails(sFirstName, sSurname, sEmailAddress, iAge, cGender); // get user details
                user.ReturnUserDetails(sFirstName, sSurname, sEmailAddress, iAge, cGender); //show user details
                if (iCount == 1)
                {
                    cout << "test" << endl; // never appears

                    break;
                }
            }
                break;
            //if user presses 2
        case 2:
            cout << "test" << endl;
            break;
            //if user presses 3
        case 3:
            break;
            //if user presses 4
        case 4:
            break;
            //default action
        default:
            menu.ShowMainMenu();
            break;


        }


    } while (iChoice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `do-while` loop will loop as long as `iChoice` is not 0. But `iChoice` cannot change within the loop - you only read it once, before the `do`.

(Your diagnostic `test` string is never printed because after one `for`-loop iteration, `i` increases to 1 and the `for`-loop immediately terminates.)

Comment: thanks, so how would I get program to return back to the main menu? by changing `iChoice` in every `case`?

Comment: More likely after the switch statement. You need to re-prompt and re-read the input. Think about how this should work for the user - they're asked what to do, enter a choice, their choice happens (that's the `switch`) - _and then they need to get asked again_.

Comment: Just looked back at your code and seen the `ShowMainMenu` in the default case. So, yes, you could just set `iChoice` to -1 (say), and let it fall through to there. Better would probably be to make the `default` case display a message to the user ("I didn't understand that"), and reprompt after the switch so each case gets it.